# Override Modal Dialog Box CSS in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog

I would like to override Modal Dialog Box CSS in SharePoint 2013.I using Below CSS in the Content Editor Web part of the Particular list Newform.aspx.But Its not overriding existing CSS.

```
iframe .ms-dlgContent {
    top:1px !important;
}
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Any Help Would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Just after you create your modal dialog, use JQuery to force the Css.

```
jQuery('.ms-dlgContent').css('top','1px');
```